# direction vector for the line in the $xy$-plane that passes the origin and makes an angle $\theta$ with the positive _x_-axis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $l$ be the line in the $xy$-plane that passes the origin and makes an angle $\theta$ with the positive *x*-axis, where $0\le\theta\lt\pi/2$.

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyWVw.png)

Where, 
My question is to find equation of line or direction vector on *l*.

thanks

Comment: Check [Householder matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation).

Answer (score 0):

You can think about it this way: you first rotate your vector by $-\theta$, project onto the $x$ axis, and then rotate back. The resulting matrix is the product of the corresponding matrices.